# Protect a directory with regular Laravel Auth

Tags: authentication, laravel, laravel-4

I have a secondary application that drops new folders into my Laravel application on a daily basis. The contents of the folder need to be publicly accessible because they're flash files with a number of assets placed in each day's folder, alongside static `.html` pages, `.jpgs`, and `.swfs`. These links are part of the secondary application's vendor-coded framework.

Moving the files from a non-web accessible folder using php doesn't seem like a good option. I've tried using `readfile()` and considered `.htaccess`, but I don't want a secondary login for my users.

Only users who have logins with my Laravel application should have access to these files. Is there some way I can protect access to any request inside this folder with Laravel's Auth system, not basic auth? With the understanding that the page requests inside that folder vary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From extensive searching, I've found that Laravel cannot handle the protection of public folders with static assets. This is a web server configuration issue.

One solution would be to set a cookie that gets read by the web server and bounces the user if the cookie value does not match a predetermined value. But Laravel encrypts cookies and disposes of cookies not encrypted on each load. So that solution would only work if you use App::filter to process the cookie using php setcookie().